# Issue while loading BIM files in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

When viewing files in Autodesk forge viewer, getting some errors like 
•   “Cannot read property ‘setEndpoint’ of undefined”
•   “doc.getRootItem is not a function”
And will be able to view after hard reload (Ctrl + Shift +R) the page. Sometimes the same errors will get again even after hard reload and clear cache the browser.

```
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    accessToken: getAccessToken() //Method to get access token- no errors here
};
var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
});

//Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load - success function.
function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        debugger;
    }, 5000);

//Error is thrown in the line below.                
    var viewables = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {
        'type': 'geometry'
    }, true); //throws error on calling doc.getRootItem()

    if (viewables.length === 0) {
        console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
        return;
    }
    // Choose any of the avialble viewables
    var initialViewable = viewables[0];
    var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
    var modelOptions = {
        sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath()
    };

    var viewerDiv = document.getElementById('divViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
    viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to Viewer v7 pls use `doc.getRoot()` - `doc.getRootItem()` has been deprecated:

```
 NOP_VIEWER.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry());
```

See live sample [here](https://jsbin.com/pekohet/4/edit?js) and migration guide to v7 [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/).